# distinct and case within WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank

can I able to use a case after the where clause. below is my query.

Thanks,

```
select unit_id, law_id, risk, count(risk) as crr
                            from schema.table1 
                            group by unit_id, law_id, risk
          order by crr desc, risk desc
```

results

```
unit_id |law_id | risk      | crr
----------------------------------
|   1   | 3     |Significant| 3 
|   1   | 3     |Limited    | 3
|   3   | 2     |Significant| 1
|   1   | 1     |Significant| 1
|   2   | 2     |Medium     | 1
|   1   | 3     |Critical   | 1
```

and when I rank them

```
select unit_id, law_id, a.risk, 
                            rank() OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id, law_id ORDER BY crr DESC, risk DESC ) as rank
            from (select unit_id, law_id, risk, count(risk) as crr
                            from schema.table1 
                            group by unit_id, law_id, risk
          order by crr desc, risk desc                              
           ) a
```

results

```
unit_id |law_id | risk      | rank
----------------------------------
|   1   | 1     |Significant| 1 
|   1   | 3     |Significant| 1
|   1   | 3     |Limited    | 2
|   1   | 3     |Critical   | 3
|   2   | 2     |Medium     | 1
|   3   | 2     |Significant| 1
```

I am getting the below results with my query. but I want to get all the ranks that are 1 and ignore rank 1 and get Critical(whatever the rank is) if there is any from above results.
I want to get the results that is something like below.

```
select unit_id, law_id, risk FROM                
            (select unit_id, law_id, a.risk, 
                            rank() OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id, law_id ORDER BY crr DESC, risk DESC ) as rank
            from (select unit_id, law_id, risk, count(risk) as crr
            from schema.table1 group by unit_id, law_id, risk
          order by crr desc, risk desc      
           ) a  )b WHERE rank = 1 or risk = 'Critical'
```

actual results

```
unit_id |law_id | risk      
----------------------------
|   1   | 1     |Significant
|   1   | 3     |Significant
|   1   | 3     |Critical
|   2   | 2     |Medium    
|   3   | 2     |Significant
```

Expected Results

```
unit_id |law_id | risk      
----------------------------
|   1   | 1     |Significant
|   1   | 3     |Critical
|   2   | 2     |Medium    
|   3   | 2     |Significant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `RANK()` `ORDER BY` :

```
select unit_id, law_id, risk FROM                
            (select unit_id, law_id, a.risk, 
                     rank() OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id, law_id 
                                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN risk = 'Critical' then 1 else 0 end DESC, crr DESC, risk DESC ) as rank
            from (select unit_id, law_id, risk, count(risk) as crr
            from schema.table1 group by unit_id, law_id, risk
          order by crr desc, risk desc      
           ) a  )b WHERE rank = 1
```

That way, the `critical` will get ranked as 1 first, and the rest will get ranked by your logic.

Comment: No problem :) @Taz